# Purchasing Optimization Problem

Tags: optimization, time-series

I apologize in advance if this question is not formatted up to standards, as this is my first time asking a math related question on here.

I am currently working on a problem for work that I have recognized to be an optimization problem.

A bit of background. The problem I am working on involves purchasing a specific commodity, so the overarching goal is to determine when to purchase and how much to purchase at that time to minimize a specific metric (in this case, days on hand). The data I am given is grouped into weeks. When purchasing items, we are purchasing $8$ weeks in advance. For this particular problem, we are assuming that our forecasts are accurate. In addition to this, we have to buy a full train car of this commodity, which is approximately $195$ thousand pounds (so we can only buy multiples of $195$ thousand pounds). With that in mind, I have created the following optimization problem.

For simplification, let's say we are only purchasing for $3$ weeks rather than $8$.
The following are the equations and the conditions for the optimization:

```
Week_1_Qty= Initial_Qty - Forecast_week_1 + 195x_1
Week_2_Qty = Week_1_Qty - Forecast_week_2 + 195x_2
Week_3_Qty = Week_2_Qty - Forecast_week_3 + 195x_3
```

Initial_Qty, and the forecast at each week are all constants.

I am trying to minimize the following calculation of days on hand for the full three weeks in which I am purchasing(NOTE: this is not the typical financial calculation). More specifically, I am trying to find the values for $X_i$ that minimize the days on hand for this period.

```
sum(Week_i_QTY)/ 3*Avg_Daily_Useage
```

Average daily useage is also a constant.

The only conditional statements I have are the following:

```
Week_1_Qty>0
Week_2_Qty>0
Week_3_Qty>0
```

I am not too familiar with optimization. Have I set up this optimization problem correctly and what type of optimization would I use to solve this. I am also unsure as to whether the constraints I created are set up properly (I only want to make sure that the quantity of the commodity does not go negative at any week). I was thinking linear programming, but am not for sure if this is the correct way to approach this problem.

Any advice is greatly appreciated. Once again, I apologize for the poor formatting.

I have tried running through these on online linear optimization calculators with some values for the equations I have given above and keep getting error messages on the equation I am attempting to optimize and I am unsure what I am doing wrong.

Do you believe the way that I set this up is the correct way to go about doing this? If not, what would some alternatives be.

Comment: I just adjusted what those equations were. They should be correct now! Sorry about that.

Comment: You want $\ge 0$, not $> 0$.  In general, optimal solutions may not exist when you have $>$ constraints: you can get solutions where the difference of the two sides is arbitrarily small, but the limit of these (which would be optimal) has $=$ rather than $>$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael the variables seem to be integers, the other way $195\cdot$ doesn't make sense (why not to include it into the variable instead).

Answer (score 1):

Let consider a *planning time period* made of m weeks.
Let be $ x_1, x_2 , \dots , x_m $ the *quantity* (measured in **pounds**) *of the specific commodity* to be purchased for every week in order to meet the demand. The demand for every week is known in advance and it is forecasted with a relative error (standard deviation/mean) less than 3%:

$ d_1, d_2 , \dots , d_m $

The lead time for getting the commodity from supplier requires 8 weeks and as a result it is necessary to place the purchase order in advance of 8 weeks:

$ x(t - \tau) = x_t $ where $ \tau = 8 $ weeks

For example, if today we got as optimal solution for third week x_3 = 100 pound, this means that we should place the order five weeks in advance from today, $ x_3 = x(3 - 8)  $

Because of a full train car is able to carry $k$=195,000 pounds of the commodities, we designate as

$ y_1, y_2 , \dots , y_m $

the *number of train car* to be hired for every specific week. Clearly $ y_i $ is a natural number.

Let $ INV_0 $ be the stock on hand at the beginning of planning time period.

The constraint that balances purchasing, demand and inventory is:

$ x_i + INV_{i-1} – INV_i = d_i $ for $i=1, \dots , m $

So, $ y_i \ge x_i / k $ where k = 195,000 pounds and therefore we request that

$ k y_i \ge d_i - INV_{i-1} + INV_i $

**The goal is to keep the days on hand of commodity as minimum as possible without shortage in every week AND to hire the minimum number of train cars**.

The mathematical model as PL can be written as:

$ min \left \{ \sum_{i = 1}^m y_i + \sum_{i=1}^m INV_i \right \} $

subject to:

$ \left\{ \begin{array}{l} 
k y_1 \ge d_1 - INV_0 + INV_1  \\ 
k y_2 \ge d_2 - INV_1 + INV_2 \\ 
\vdots \\
k y_m \ge d_m - INV_{m-1} + INV_m \\  \\
INV_i \ge 0   \forall \ i  \\
y_i \in N    \forall \ i
\end{array} \right. $