# Optimization Problem Help- Purchasing

Tags: optimization

I posted this problem the other day on the forum and am currently completely stumped on how to proceed.
[Purchasing Optimization Problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3806578/purchasing-optimization-problem)

I have coded this problem in R with the data that this information is from such that the objective function does not contain any of the constants. The objective function is as follows:

```
3*195x1/(Average_Weekly_usage) + 2*195x2/(Average_Weekly_usage) + 195_x3/(Average_Weekly_usage)
```

which could then simplify down further to just:

```
3x1 + 2x2 +1x3
```

Once again, I have coded all of the constraints as given in the previous post. Yet, when I run the code, the answer is $\sim155,000$ which should absolutely be nowhere near the correct solution. I am frankly very stumped as to what I am doing incorrectly to get this answer. I believe it has to be something I did wrong setting up the objective or the constraints, rather than a coding error. Is there anything that is glaringly obvious that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your question has some serious number issues and there is one thing in particular that is what is the value of Average_daily_usage

Comment: Made a correction to the formula as to what it should be. But to answer your question, average *weekly* useage is a constant that is essentially a historical average that is manipulated to give a weekly value. @s